# When I create a custom search folder in Outlook that uses "Read equals No" criteria, reply does not work

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search-folder

I tried to create a custom search folder similar to the non-custom "Mail either unread or flagged for follow up" folder, but it is not working as expected. I am using the Query Builder. My criteria is the following:

("Read equals No" OR ("Follow Up Flag is not empty" AND "Flag Status not equal to Completed" AND "Due Date on or before today")) AND "In Folder doesn't contain Drafts" AND "In Folder doesn't contain 'Deleted Items'"

The problem that I am having is that "Read equals No" does not behave the same as UnRead in the non-custom search folder. In my custom search folder, as soon as an email becomes read, it disappears. That would be ok, except that one of the ways an email becomes read is by replying to it. As soon as I hit the reply button, the email disappears and I cannot reply.

The non-custom search folder gets around this by leaving read emails in the search folder until you navigate away from the folder and come back.

I don't see any way to do that in custom search folders. Maybe there is some other way to get reply to work somehow? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of adding "Unread" to criteria, we can first set other three conditions and then filter unread emails by view.

Comment: @Perry if I do not add unread to the criteria, then there will be no unread emails to filter.